# Expected value of a gamma-distributed random variable to the n-th power?

Tags: pr.probability

Is there a closed form for $E(Y^n)$, where $Y$ is a random variable with a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of reading it off the moment generating function? Gives alpha(alpha+1)...(alpha+n-1)beta^n.

Comment: mm yeah i forgot about those. I just figured it out by doing the integrals by hand.

Comment: It's been a while since you posted this, but I will claim my answer is better than the one you accepted because it shows you how routine the integral is, and exactly how to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape parameter is $\alpha$ and the scale parameter $\beta$, then $E(Y^r) = \beta^r \Gamma(\alpha + r)/\Gamma(\alpha)$ for real $r > 0$.

Comment: Odd that you write $\Gamma(\alpha+r)/\Gamma(\alpha)$ without mentioning that this simplifies to $\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2) \cdots (\alpha+r-1). \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

For now I will assume you mean
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac y\beta\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-y/\beta} \, \frac{dy}\beta \text{ for } y>0
$$
rather than
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \beta y\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta y} (\beta\, dy) \text{ for } y>0.
$$
The expected value is:
\begin{align}
\operatorname E\left( Y^n \right) & = \int_0^\infty y^n f_Y(y)\, dy \\[12pt]
& = \int_0^\infty y^n \cdot \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac y\beta\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-y/\beta} \, \frac{dy}\beta \\[12pt]
& = \frac{\beta^n}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty \left( \frac y \beta \right)^{n+\alpha-1} e^{-y/\beta} \, \frac{dy}\beta \\[12pt]
& = \frac{\beta^n \Gamma(\alpha+n)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \\[12pt]
& = \beta^n \, \underbrace{\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)}_\text{$n$ factors}.
\end{align}

So the only integral is the one that usually defines the gamma function.